# Accessing a checkbox value(True/False) from diff form On-Load Event code

Tags: ms-access, vba

**strong text**Need help to identify the error which is occurring while I'm referencing a Checkbox value inside a if statement in Form's OnLoad event Code. Basically checkbox name is "chkEditFinalized" and is placed in diff Form named "Settings" Under 3rd tab "ActionTriggers". Below is the event code.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

        Dim YorN As Boolean

        If ([Forms]![Settings]![chkEditFinalized].Value = True) Then


        'Codes to execute


        Else

        'Codes to execute

        End If        
End Sub
```

On the error message window it says "RunTime Error 2450, Application cannot find the referenced from settings"

Can somebody tell me what i have done wrong?

**Edit----**: As I know that my intention is not possible to implement(as explained by Wolfgang Kais), Can somebody advice me on how to make a global variable and make it accessible from all forms which I've tried and failed(Error:" Variable not defined" While running a sub function even the variable was declared in a Separate module). I know I may sound like a stupid because I'm no expert in this. If I can do this it will fulfill my requirement.

Expecting your valuable advice.
Thanks..

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to check the value on the different form ("Settings"), that form "Settigns" must neither be closed not open in design view. It has to be open.

Comment: Well, that explains all. Already spend a lot of time on searching for a solution, But still happy with the reason :) . Thank you very much for your reply.